# Iterating through an array in order to mark checkboxes

Tags: php, jquery

I have an array that was passed to Jquery from PHP.  The array contains input values from checkboxes.  I want to now use the values from the array to mark the checkboxes as checked again.  Here is my code that is not working:

```
//pass PHP array to JQuery
var array = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>; 

//use each array value to select and check the checkboxes
$.each( array, function( index, value ){
  $("input[value='value']").prop('checked',true); 
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try `$("input[value='" + value + "']")...` Unlike PHP, JavaScript will not automatically concat your variables inside your single quotes

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!  Now only the first checkbox from the array of values is being marked.  For some reason the code isn't iterating through the whole array to check all of the checkboxes.

Comment: The problem is solved now, War10ck, mostly thanks to you.  I just needed to use trim(value) to solve the issue.  Thanks again!